# cellClass is not working for angular ui grid

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

Here is my code:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < gridData.length; i++) {
    var currentData = gridData
    $.each(currentData, function(key, value) {
        if (!angular.isFunction(value)) {
            $scope.columnDefs.push({
                name : key,
                cellClass : 'red',
            });
        }
    });
}
$scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs : $scope.columnDefs
};
$scope.gridOptions.data = data;
```

```css
.red{
 background-color: #ff0000;
 color: #ffffff; 
}
```

```html
<div ng-controller="GridController" id="grid1">
     <div  ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
</div>
```

When I replace `cellClass` property from `columnDefs` array it's absolutely worked fine but when I add `cellClass` property to `columnDefs` array my grid doesn't display data. On inspecting `ui-grid dom` my data is binded with `ui-grid cell` but doesn't appear on ui.

Comment: I don't think `name : key` is correct, you're binding an object to what the grid expects as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply overide this two css class in ui.grid.css

```css
   .ui-grid-row:nth-child(odd) .ui-grid-cell {

}
.ui-grid-row:nth-child(even) .ui-grid-cell {

}
```

Remove background-color css from the above mention css classes in ui-grid.css

Comment: Right, but cellClass should work, you should not need to overwrite the ui-grid.css.

Answer (score -2):

Use `cellTemplate` instead of `cellClass`.

Example:

```
cellTemplate: "<div class='red'>{{COL_FIELD}}</div>"
```